# facebook connect not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

This all is driving me nuts.
I just integrated facebook in my iphone app.
After typing in my username and password in the login dialog this method is called.

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result {
    if ([request.method isEqualToString:@"facebook.fql.query"]) {
        NSLog(@"result %@",result);

            NSArray* users = result;
            NSLog(@"users %@",users);
            NSDictionary* user = [users objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString* name = [user objectForKey:@"name"];
            self.facebookName = name;       

            if (_posting) {
                [self postToWall];
                _posting = NO;
            }


    }
}
```

But after this the app crashes most of the times and when I tried to log the "`result`" array it appears to be empty. Why is it so?

What should I do? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reason for this.

This was due to the session getting lost frequently in between.
So I had to call [session resume] in the facebook login action event
and in this manner if at all the session is lost by any chance then the previous session is resumed and the "`result`" does not appears to be nil in  `(void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result` method.

Hope this helps out those who are stuck in the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
NSArray *users=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:result, nil];
        NSLog(@"users %@",users);
        NSDictionary* user = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:users,@"users", nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",user);
```